# variable usage problems with async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
var async = require('async');

var list = [1,2,3,4,5];

var functions = [];

for(i in list){
    var f = function(call){
        console.log(list[i]);
        call();
    }
}

async.parallel(functions,function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('finish first try');
});

async.parallel([function(call){
    for(i in list){
        console.log(list[i]);
        if(i == list.length-1)
            call();
    }
}],function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('finish second try');
});
```

log :

finish first try

1

2

3

4

5

finish second try

function does not work when added as array. why can't I see the numbers at first try? Why not return?

Comment: In `for(i in list){ var f = function(call){ console.log(list[i]); call(); } }` - I think you have to call f() to get the function executed...

Answer (score 0):

Because you not fill `functions` array and need this:

```
for(i in list){
    var f = function(call){
        console.log(list[i]);
        call();
    }
    functions.push(f);
}
```

Or if you need iterate `i`:

```
for(i in list){
    var f = (function(i) {
        return function(call){
          console.log(list[i]);
          call();
       };
    })(i);
    functions.push(f);
}
```